# external javascript not reading variables

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me with this one?

Basically, my external javascript file is not reading my variable list. 
It is reading the document. title call above, and when I literally cut and paste the code into an internal javascript file it reads fine so I'm stumped.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>javascript</title>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="ourheadline">Click this to replace text</h1>
    <button>Add new item</button>

    <ul id="our-list">
        <li>1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
        <li>4th item</li>
    </ul>
</body>

<script>
   var listBoxes = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
    </script>

</html>

and the javascript

document.title = "This is a latest newset text";
```

var listBoxes = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");

Like I say the document.title reads fine but the list doesn't read at all it just returns as undefined in the console
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This has  nothing to do with the JS being in an external file. It has everything to do with you *moving the `<script>` element from the bottom to the top of the file*.

Comment: to extend Quentin's comment, your page code is read sequentially from top to bottom, an external script is executed when the `<script>` tag is met. If the html element you try to get is declared after, it will not exist yet for your script

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside document or window load to access elements

```
window.onload=function(){
 var listBoxes = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
}
```

in `Jquery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var listBoxes = document.getElementById("our-list").getElementsByTagName("li");

});
```